# local #includes

Tags: c++, include

Is there some way to #include standard things locally (for one function, one class, etc... at a time) instead of globally. Taking a very simple example one might want to use std::string but it is only needed in one class and you don't want the overhead of it existing everywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of making `#include` local, you should probably just move the class that requires it into a separate file.

Comment: Would parts of the main program that come after the #include that includes (the class using the string and the #include <string>) have access to std::string in this case?

Comment: @alan2here: If you `#include <string>` in the class header (.h), then your main program will also have access to it when you include the class. If you `#include <string>` in the class implementation (.cpp), then it is visible only in that file.

Answer (score 3):

Since `#include` is simply just a kind of text replacement before compilation (by the [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)), it is just a matter of where you put the include statement.

Likely, you are refering to "locally" as "*in just one .cpp file*" and to "globally" as "*in all .cpp files*".

If this is true, you can make an `#include` as "locally" by only including in that .cpp files where you want it. If you want to include a file with one `#include` statement in several files, place the include statement into a .h file and include that .h file inside all required files.

A good place to make a "global" `#include` is the .h header file that serves as the [precompiled header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header).

Answer (score 2):

One way to do the thing you want is use a nested class like `class IMPL` and use a pointer to that as a member in your class. you define and implement that `your_class::IMPL` in separate files. That way you achief total data hiding.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the definition of `std::string` in a local header (that's it, located in your project directory).

This is not an easy job, anyway, especially for a template class like `std::string`: since it's a template it'll need the whole declaration, and your program, at runtime, will use the `std::string` as declared in your header.

Besides different STL implementations could implement `std::string` in different ways, although the interface *should* be the same.

So the short answer is: no, use the system headers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you will #include something in a .cpp file , you will not get access to this header in other files. But if you #include a.h in a b.h file and then #include b.h in c.cpp i think you will have access to a.h in c.cpp