# Is there a clean approach for includes in dynamic templates?

Tags: c++

I wondered about this:

Let's say you have a template class that is to be kept dynamic. As a result, you have to implement it in a header file.

Now say you have several includes in that header file which would usually belong in a source file, like for example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
```

The result of this is that every time that one includes your template class, all of those will also be included. This makes me stumble a little bit here - this looks, in a way, dirty.

So my question is, is there a way to do this *better*? Without leaving the concept of a dynamic template class, that is.

On SO, I found [local #includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700786/local-includes), but in that one, the answers are about putting the includes in a source file.

Comment: I would say that no, there is no way in general. If you include `iostream` just to implement a custom stream operator, then that can be replaced by `iosfwd`. But that's hardly a general thing.

Comment: I don't think there's a way since templates have to generate new type on the fly wherever requested, and to generate that type all declarations are needed

Comment: I used to not include any header files, and let the user of my header file include the necessary headers when and as needed. I changed my mind though, as including in your own header file itself improves locality and readers can easily see your dependencies. It also makes code more maintainable and less prone to errors because of missing includes if you make changes that changes header file dependencies.

Comment: Some things you can forward declare in headers, unfortunately you cant (in a standard allowed manner) declare many types from the standard library, or many other libraries. So really you just have to live with it to a large extent, even in non-template code (e.g. function params and returns, private members, etc.) or if you put the template implementation seperately (very occasionally, in some projects you might find say `ipp` files doing this).

Comment: The short answer is: no, there is no better way.

Comment: You can also sometime split an header file in parts if a depedency only affect some functions and those are seldom used... And you might want to pay attention to the fact that maybe some headers do not depends on template arguments and put those function outside of the template code.

Comment: this restriction is also always concerns me then implementing templates. I think that is a lack in c++. there should be something like a special file type or file section that contains the template implementation and there the compiler looks if it instantiates templates but that are not visible (from a scope and maybe preprocessing view) to the including file.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "looks, in a way, dirty". Typically people have concerns about growing large include tree slowing down compilation when project has multiple translation units and getting dependent on additional header files that aren't actually required in current project. First is solved with switching to SCU paradigm, second can be typically solved with adjusting header granularity, introducing traits and/or some conditional compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no solution.

Let's assume for the sake of readability that your template has a single template parameter `T`. Now, if your template uses `std::find<std::vector<T>::iterator, T>` it's fairly obvious that it needs both `T` and `<algorithm>`. This is already the case in the first phase of template compilation (remember, templates are usually compiled twice - when it's first encountered, and when it's instantiated)

Now look at an instantiation of your template, for `T==std::string>`. This will therefore require implicit instantiation of `std::find<std::vector<std::string>::iterator, std::string>` - the second time your template is compiled. You still need `<algorithm>`. You also need `std::string`, but including `<string>` is the reponsibility of the code who instantiated your template with `std::string>`.